# Unable to update ubuntu 16

Tags: ubuntu, perl, dpkg

After executing apt-get update iam unable to install any packages.

```
# dpkg --configure -a

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libperl5.22:amd64:
 libperl5.22:amd64 depends on perl-modules-5.22 (>= 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.2); however:
  Version of perl-modules-5.22 on system is 5.22.1-9.

dpkg: error processing package libperl5.22:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of perl:
 perl depends on perl-modules-5.22 (>= 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.2); however:
  Version of perl-modules-5.22 on system is 5.22.1-9.
 perl depends on libperl5.22 (= 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.2); however:
  Package libperl5.22:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package perl (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: error processing package perl-modules-5.22 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libperl5.22:amd64
 perl
 perl-modules-5.22
```

How to solve the issue?

Comment: did you try a `apt install -f`

Comment: hi mike thanks for the reply.I have tried it and it works fine now.could u pls explain what exactly apt install -f will does.....

Comment: attempts to fix any apt/dpkg errors that happen

Comment: Did you ensure all packages are up to date? I usually run `apt-get update` followed by `apt-get dist-upgrade` to ensure all packages are up to date, that tends to resolve most of the dependency problems.

Answer (score 1):

As error message says you can try reinstalling application using below command

```
sudo apt-get  install --reinstall perl-modules-5.22
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to reinstall the package "perl-base".

```
apt-get --reinstall install perl-base
```